# LINQ accessing drives

Tags: linq

I would like to know if LINQ can be used to access the drives on my computer. I have some data stored in the drives and am performing a search on it. Can LINQ be used for this?
Thanks!

Comment: you can make cheese with LINQ. Now what's the specific programming question?

Comment: I agree that this question isn't terribly well-defined, but it seems a reasonable enough question that it doesn't need to be closed. That said, I'd be interested in seeing how to make cheese (or other dairy products) with LINQ.

Comment: Jalepeno havarti cheese mmmmmm.

Comment: Come on mitch show us how to make cheese in linq.

Comment: What do you want to search for? File names? Directory names? Modification dates? Data within the file? What's the format? We need to know what you're actually looking for before anyone can give a really meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague.I have DICOM (.dcm extension) files on my computer in any drive, for example C, and i need to search for the file names using LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is commonly used to operate over `IEnumerable` collections, and many methods in the `System.IO` namespace return `IEnumerable`s. So, yes.

For example:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
var matches = from infos in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
              where infos.CreationTime > DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
              select infos.Name;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can start by looking at [LINQ and File Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397911.aspx) on MSDN.

Based on your comment (looking for .dcm files), take a look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546159.aspx) on MSDN. It looks for .txt files, so it should be close enough to what you need to get started.